# How to dynamically add custom class variables without a constructor in Python

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

How can class variables be dynamically be added to a Python class without calling its constructor? This is required when adding custom query fields in a custom Django Graphene Relay Node filter.

In the example code below, the `is_controller` class variable is defined statically. How can the name of the variable and the parameters for the BooleanFilter be dynamically generated without using a constructor or code outside the class?

This is needed to run GraphQL queries such as `allSiteEntities(is_controller: true) { ... }`

```py
class SiteEntityFilter(FilterSet):
    """Filter for SiteEntityNode that includes component filters"""

    is_controller = BooleanFilter(
        field_name=controller_component, lookup_expr="isnull", exclude=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = SiteEntity
        fields = {
            "site": ["exact"],
            "name": ["exact", "icontains", "istartswith"],
            "modified_at": ["exact", "gt", "lt"],
        }


class SiteEntityNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteEntity
        filterset_class = SiteEntityFilter
        fields = [
            "id",
            "site",
            "name",
            "controller_component",
            "created_at",
            "modified_at",
        ]
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding the dynamic data into the settings, it is possible to dynamically add filters and fields to GraphQL queries. The problem is that the constructor is not called, which is why the `__init__()` function cannot be used and `setattr()` after the class definition also does not work. However, when using `locals()` it is possible to add class variables that are also picked up by the Graphene Relay interface code.

The custom filter is useful to check for the existence of a reverse ForeignKey with a user friendly name.

```py
# my_project/settings.py
SITE_ENTITY_COMPONENTS = [
    "controller_component",
    "peripheral_component", 
    "hydroponic_system_component",
    "water_cycle_component",
]


# my_app/graphql.py
class SiteEntityFilter(FilterSet):
    """Filter for SiteEntityNode that includes component filters"""

    for component in settings.SITE_ENTITY_COMPONENTS:
        # controller_component --> is_controller
        attribute_name = f"is_{component.split('_component')[0]}"
        locals()[attribute_name] = BooleanFilter(
            field_name=component, lookup_expr="isnull", exclude=True
        )

    class Meta:
        model = SiteEntity
        fields = {
            "site": ["exact"],
            "name": ["exact", "icontains", "istartswith"],
            "modified_at": ["exact", "gt", "lt"],
        }

class SiteEntityNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteEntity
        filterset_class = SiteEntityFilter
        fields = [
            "id",
            "site",
            "name",
            "created_at",
            "modified_at",
        ].extend(settings.SITE_ENTITY_COMPONENTS)
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```